# Splash screen shining on logo

Tags: html, css

I have tried some codes to make my logo shining using CSS3. Unfortunately the result was not so nice. Have a look my snippet what I've done.

p/s: The border of the flash makes my splash screen not so nice.

My expected output:

Shining move along the logo.

```css
/*Splash screen*/
body
{
  background-color:#ccc;
 }
.middle-screen
{
    height: 100px;
    /* margin-top: 31vh;*/
    width: 74%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

i.splash {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* ff3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(0%, rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255,255,255,0))); /* safari4+,chrome */
    background:-webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* safari5.1+,chrome10+ */
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* ie10+ */
    background:radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* w3c */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#FFFFFF', endColorstr='#FFFFFF',GradientType=0 ); /* ie6-9 */
    width: 20%;
    height: 72px;
    transform: skew(-10deg, 0deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-10deg, 0deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-10deg, 0deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-10deg, 0deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-10deg, 0deg);
    animation: move 5s;
    /*animation-iteration-count: infinite;*/
    animation-delay: 300ms;
    -webkit-animation: move 5s;
    /*-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;*/
    -webkit-animation-delay: 300ms;
    -moz-transform: skew(-10deg, 0deg);
    -moz-animation: move 5s;
    /*-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;*/
    -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
    -ms-transform: skew(-10deg, 0deg);
    -ms-animation: move 5s;
    /*-ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;*/
    -ms-animation-delay: 1s;
    -o-transform: skew(-10deg, 0deg);
    -o-animation: move 5s;
    /*-o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;*/
    -o-animation-delay: 1s;
    margin-top: 39vh;
}

/*  */
@keyframes move {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  48% {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  100% {
    left: 82%;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes move {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  48% {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  100% {
    left: 82%;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes move {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  48% {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  100% {
    left: 88%;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes move {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  48% {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  100% {
    left: 82%;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes move {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  48% {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  100% {
    left: 82%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-splash">
  <div class="middle-screen">
    <img width="100%" src="http://jiayuhk.com/sc/assets/img/sample/shortcode/logo/1.png" />
    <i class="splash"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I removed the `margin-top: 31vh;`from `.middle-screen`. Perhaps this is what you wanted:

```css
/*Splash screen*/
body
{
  background-color:#ccc;
 }
.middle-screen
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 74%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

i.splash {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* ff3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(0%, rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255,255,255,0))); /* safari4+,chrome */
    background:-webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* safari5.1+,chrome10+ */
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* ie10+ */
    background:radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* w3c */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#FFFFFF', endColorstr='#FFFFFF',GradientType=0 ); /* ie6-9 */
    width: 20%;
    height: 72px;
    transform: skew(-10deg, 0deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-10deg, 0deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-10deg, 0deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-10deg, 0deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-10deg, 0deg);
    animation: move 5s;
    /*animation-iteration-count: infinite;*/
    animation-delay: 300ms;
    -webkit-animation: move 5s;
    /*-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;*/
    -webkit-animation-delay: 300ms;
    -moz-transform: skew(-10deg, 0deg);
    -moz-animation: move 5s;
    /*-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;*/
    -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
    -ms-transform: skew(-10deg, 0deg);
    -ms-animation: move 5s;
    /*-ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;*/
    -ms-animation-delay: 1s;
    -o-transform: skew(-10deg, 0deg);
    -o-animation: move 5s;
    /*-o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;*/
    -o-animation-delay: 1s;
    margin-top: 39vh;
}

/*  */
@keyframes move {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  48% {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  100% {
    left: 82%;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes move {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  48% {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  100% {
    left: 82%;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes move {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  48% {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  100% {
    left: 88%;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes move {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  48% {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  100% {
    left: 82%;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes move {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  48% {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  100% {
    left: 82%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-splash">
  <div class="middle-screen">
    <img width="100%" src="http://jiayuhk.com/sc/assets/img/sample/shortcode/logo/1.png" />
    <i class="splash"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still not fulfill my requirement, if you can also remove border of the flash all 4 sides then its better.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the margin-top from your .middle_screen and you should be good to go.